# Beamer: How text wrapping around a graphic right aligned?

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment, wrap

I want to include a graphic in beamer presentation with right alignment and this graphic should be wrapping by text. I tried three packages but non of them works correct (minimal example below).

`picins`: the text superimposed on the graphic.

`wrapfig`: the graphic is inserted in principle to a new page following

`floatflt`: the graphic is moved to the area where the frametitle is

Another possibility to achieve this is to put the graphic into a column, but then it's not wrapping by text.

Is there anyone who knows how I can solve this?

```
    \documentclass[11pt,t,handout]{beamer}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

    \usepackage{picins}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{floatflt}

    \author{Max Mustermann}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Folientitel}
    \piccaption{Caption}
    \parpic[r]{\includegraphics{grafik}}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
      \item Punkt 1 = text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah         foo bar
      \item Punkt 2
      \item Punkt 3
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}


    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Folientitel}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm}
    \includegraphics{grafik}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
      \item Punkt 1
      \item Punkt 2
      \item Punkt 3
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}


    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Folientitel}
    \begin{floatingfigure}[r]{5cm}
    \includegraphics{grafik}
    \end{floatingfigure}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
      \item Punkt 1
      \item Punkt 2
      \item Punkt 3
    \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: If you're still interested in an automate solution, please see my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56228/3954 .

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Thanks for the answer. The issue described here is different, because the text consists in itemize environment. And what I know now -- and it's a question to this issue in general -- in LaTeX it's impossible that text in itemize environment wrapping around something like a picture.

Answer (score 23):

One basic idea could be use a `minipage` and divide it in two `columns`: on the right put the image and on the left the text. This method is not perfect, but gives you at least something similar to a wrapped figure.

Here is my code with a test image:

```
\documentclass[11pt,t,handout]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{EastLansing}
\author{Max Mustermann}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Folientitel}

\begin{minipage}[0.2\textheight]{\textwidth}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Punkt 1 = text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar
\item Punkt 2= text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar
\item Punkt 3= text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logopolito}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{minipage}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item Punkt 1 = text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar
\item Punkt 2= text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar
\item Punkt 3= text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which gives you as result:

[image]

Comment: Grazie! It's a possibility, but not what I'm searching for. Because it depends on how large (height) the graphic is and so it's not automatable -- and this is normally the great advantage of LaTeX. Maybe, there is another solution?

Comment: Is there a way to get the bullet points to line up properly without having to manually adjust the column width parameters or `\hspace`?

Comment: I think you have to play with the column parameters, but this really depends on your real needs and consequently on how the frame should have to be built.

Answer (score 14):

For proper alignment of the items in the list you can set the items that require wrapping inside a `\parbox` of pre-specified width. This allows you to put all the items in the same list:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58087/5764
%\usepackage{graphicx} Already loaded by beamer
\usetheme{EastLansing}
\author{Max Mustermann}

\newcommand{\lenitem}[2][.7\linewidth]{\parbox[t]{#1}{\strut #2\strut}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Folientitel}

  \mbox{}\hfill\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \vspace*{-\baselineskip}

  \begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item \lenitem{Punkt 1: text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar}
  \item \lenitem{Punkt 2: text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar}
  \item \lenitem{Punkt 3: text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar}
  \item Punkt 1: text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar
  \item Punkt 2: text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar
  \item Punkt 3: text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar, text blah blah foo bar
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Remember that these are slides that don't contain a large amount of text, so manual interference/setting is okay at times (at least in my opinion).

Answer (score 6):

If someone is looking for another way to hack around this problem, I found a method using negative space. This does not solve the wrapping problem so if the image overlaps the text, you have to manually insert newlines. But it's a quick and ugly way to insert the image where you want.

```
\begin{columns}[T]
 \column{0.99\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item blah
   \item blah
   \item blah
  \end{itemize}

 \column{0.01\textwidth}
 \hspace*{-2cm}
 \includegraphics[width=2cm]{image}
\end{columns}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `textpos`

```latex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}

\begin{textblock}{8}(1.0, 3.0)
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> this is an example
\item []
\item<2-> this is an example
\item []
\item<3-> this is an example
\end{itemize}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{14}(1.0, 9.0)
\begin{itemize}
\item<4-> this is an example this is an example this is an example
\item []
\item<5-> this is an example this is an example this is an example
\item []
\item<6-> this is an example this is an example this is an example
\end{itemize}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{5}(9.0, 3.5)
\includegraphics[width=1.0 \textwidth]{example-image-golden}
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which needs some manual adjustment, here it is

[image: wrap figure]