# Wrapfigure beamer style

Tags: beamer, wrapfigure

I want to add a graphic plot to my slide, but if I do it with `wrapfigure`, I get no error massages, but the plot simply does not appear?

Code of the TeX file, which uses `beamerdefs.sty`, I have also added the wrapfig package:

```
\begin{frame}{EWMA Plot}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{ewma2.jpg}
  \end{center}
  \caption{EWMA}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{frame}
```

As I said, no error message, it just does not appear, if I do it without `wrapfigure` the graphic appears? Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you can have a look to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53998/beamer-how-text-wrapping-around-a-graphic-right-aligned).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I've removed the thanks. It can seem a little strange, but it's just the style here.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`cutwin`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cutwin) package instead of `wrapfig`; a little example showing also the settings to provide a caption consistent with regular captions:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{%
  \includegraphics[height=4cm, width=3cm]{ctanlion}
  \par{\usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}%
  \usebeamerfont*{caption name}\figurename%
  \usebeamertemplate{caption label separator}}%
  \raggedright%
  \usebeamerfont*{caption}%
  A figure with wrapping text.%
}
\opencutleft
\vfill

\begin{cutout}{0}{0pt}{.65\linewidth}{13}
\lipsum[1]
\end{cutout}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: seems nice! But text will not take into account the beamer themes upper bands, lower bands etc? Try adding `\usetheme{Berkeley}` to your example...  any idea how to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: When my text had new lines it caused the text to disappear off the right-hand side :(

Comment: This does not work with environments such as `itemize` and has the issue raised by @JStrahl

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It seems that the `includegraphics` command in the `wrapfigure` environment comes out blank if it is the first `includegraphics` of the document.

You can work around it by creating a blank image (e.g. `blank.pdf`) and including it before the `wrapfigure` environment.  This works for me:

```
\includegraphics[width=0pt]{blank.pdf}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{Figure_Clinical_Correlation.pdf}
\label{clincorr}
\end{wrapfigure}
```