# Beamer note page: Wrap text around slide preview

Tags: beamer, notes

I want to have a more compact nodes page: I want to have the preview of the current slide at the top right and then the text wrapping around this preview. This is similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56205/wrapfigure-beamer-style/56228#56228 just for the nodes page.

So i tried the following adaption, but it fails:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{note page}{wraptext}{
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{%
  \includegraphics{\insertslideintonotes{0.25}}
  \par{\usebeamercolor[fg]{caption name}%
  \usebeamerfont*{caption name}\figurename%
  \usebeamertemplate{caption label separator}}%
  \raggedright%
  \usebeamerfont*{caption}%
  A figure with wrapping text.%
}
\opencutleft
\vfill

\begin{cutout}{0}{0pt}{.65\linewidth}{13}
\insertnote
\end{cutout}}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[wraptext]

\setbeameroption{show notes}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\note{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

> Incompatible list can't be unboxed

Is there a comparable solution?

Comment: I've no solution but your code started to work for me if `\includegraphics` is supressed (just `\insertslideintonotes`) and some line is added over the slide (don't use `0` for first parameter in `cutout` environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `wrapfig`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}{%
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \insertslideintonotes{0.25}
        \caption{A figure with wrapping text.}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \insertnote
}

\setbeameroption{show notes}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\note{\lipsum[1]}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]