# Itemized list flowing around picture

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

I try to make a slide using beamer which is mostly a list with a small picture in the top right corner.
I can make this using columns and having two separate itemize environments, but this is really ugly, as the itemize environments do not line up and also the spacing is off.
Currently it looks like this:

[image: Current attempt]

This is the code used to create the page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                      
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                      
\begin{frame}{Fancyslide}                                                                                                                                             
\begin{columns}                                                                                                                                                       
 \begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}                                                                                                                                       
  \begin{itemize}                                                                                                                                                     
  \item First item, somewhat short                                                                                                                                    
  \item Another argument                                                                                                                                              
  \item Another argument                                                                                                                                              
  \item Long argument that should get wrapped twice because it does not fit in the line                                                                               
 \end{itemize}                                                                                                                                                        
 \end{column}                                                                                                                                                         
 \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}                                                                                                                                        
 \begin{figure}                                                                                                                                                       
  \centering                                                                                                                                                          
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}                                                                                                                           
 \end{figure}                                                                                                                                                         
 \end{column}                                                                                                                                                         
\end{columns}                                                                                                                                                         
 \begin{itemize}                                                                                                                                                      
  \item Another long argument which shall span the entire line                                                                                                        
  \item How to align the itemize environments?                                                                                                                        
  \item How to ensure that the spacing between items of the different itemize environments is consistent with the other spacings of items?                            
  \item Final argument                                                                                                                                                
 \end{itemize}                                                                                                                                                        
\end{frame}                                                                                                                                                           
\end{document}
```

Any ideas of how I can make this consistent and beautiful?
Note: (Currently) not possible with beamer/LaTeX is a perfectly acceptable answer. At least then I would know that I should stop trying.

**EDIT**: Zarko provided an answer using the wrapfig package. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce his results. Taking his code and only replacing the image names by my example image I get an aweful result with pdflatex and a not satisfying one with xelatex (writing over the image). So I guess I have run into TeX's infamous version dependency issue :-(
Looking for more stable solutions if possible.

pdflatex:
[image: pdflatex]

xelatex:
[image: xelatex]

The image I used, just in case it is causing issues:
[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56205/wrapfigure-beamer-style, it may help you

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is not bad. It gives, as I see, desired result. A little bit shorter code you can get if you use `wrapfig` package. With it you still need to split list on two parts (one for left from figure, one for bottom of of it). For example, based on the second answer on question [wrapfigure in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56205/wrapfigure-beamer-style), you can write.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Fancyslide}

\includegraphics[width=0pt]{example-image} % that next image stay on the same frame
\begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{0.3\linewidth}  
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{wrapfigure}
    \begin{itemize}
\item First item, somewhat short
\item Another argument
\item Another argument
\item Long argument that should get wrapped twice because it does not fit in the line
    \end{itemize}
    
    \begin{itemize}
\item Another long argument which shall span the entire line
\item How to align the itemize environments?
\item How to ensure that the spacing between items of the different itemize environments is consistent with the other spacings of items?
\item Final argument
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** the proposed solution works fine when MWE is compiled by pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, but not with XeLaTeX. .

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I learned something new: The wrapfig package. Unfortunately I produces rather bad results for me, see edit to my question. This may be due to version differences in the packages and latex versions we used, but that is not something I can easily solve.

Comment: I disagree with you. Your MWE does not work fine when I compiled it with pdfLaTeX. Tried in a fresh virtual environment with no other TeX available. I took my image and renamed it to example-image.png and example-image-duck.png. The image gets printed twice on the resulting pdf when opening with evince. Only once when opening with okular, but with text across the image. Maybe you should try a more square image to see if this gets overwritten. Anyways, thanks a lot for the MWE, I will bring this up with evince.

Comment: @laolux, I disagree with you. My MWE works as I advertised :-)  Tested by recent MiKTeX, result observed by Sumatra and Adobe Reader.

Comment: Well, I do not have your image available, so I cannot exactly reproduce. I think the issue that I get text written on the image comes from the fact that my image is mostly square. Yours is not as high, so it simply does not poke into the "the line" text. The text, including the line breaks, look the same in my version.

Comment: @laolux, image used in my MWE is available in `fraphicx` package which is loaded by `beamer`. SO If you test my MWE as is. You should get the same result as I show in my answer.

Comment: that sounds good, but for whatever reason my Tex Live 2021 is not shipping example-image. When I try to use pdflatex to compile your MWE in an otherwise empty directory I just get `! LaTeX Error: File `example-image' not found.` Also, I cannot find any `example-image-duck` on my computer. Using Fedora 35, installed beamer via `dnf install texlive-beamer`. I also cannot find any `example-image` or `example-image-duck` in the `graphicx` package downloaded from ctan.org. So I cannot reproduce your MWE.