# Beamer: designing slide

Tags: beamer

I would like to know if it is possible for all slides in beamer to have a rectangular region of specified dimensions where no text, mathematical expressions, or images can appear. Ideally, any text should wrap around this region automatically. The region I have in mind would be a rectangular region on the top right hand side of each slide.

Comment: I remember the exact same question being bountied two weeks ago, however I cannot locate it. Maybe someone else has more luck.

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53998/beamer-how-text-wrapping-around-a-graphic-right-aligned

Comment: Does using margins solve your problem? You can use the geometry package and change the margins. I think this should work for beamer as well. https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/page_size_and_margins

Comment: Duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625748/beamer-reserving-space-for-video-overlay-automatically